# Post to fanpage with offline_access

Tags: post, facebook-page

If I am an admin of a page. I create an app which able to post to my own page. What I have done before, I use "Graph Explorer Tool" to extend the "offline_access" then I get the token code to use when post. It work fine in the past.

Now, when I click on "Get Access Token" , goto Extended Permission, then check "offline_access", click ok. It is not remember the offline_access.

And there are no "deprecate offline_access" in advance of the app.

If someone can make it work, please share! would appreciate! Thanks

EDITED: Jan 09, 2013

After i make it work, I post the solution if someone have same problem as me.

Tool:
1- Debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)
2- Graph Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

Requirement:
You can manage an app and facebook page

To do:
1- **Enable App to Manage Page:** Goto "Graph Explorer", Select your application, Click on "Get Access Token", Go to "Extended Permission" check on "manage_page"

2- **Exchange the short-lived token for long-lived token:** This can be done by open this link on browser. But before you do, you need to replace your own information.

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=**{YOUR_OWN_APP_ID}**&client_secret=**{YOUR_OWN_APP_SECRET}**&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=**{YOUR_OWN_SHORT_LIVED_TOKEN}**

After you open this link, if everything is ok, you will get new access token code. Use Debugger to check this token, you will see this token can live in 2 months.

3- **Get Page Access Token:** Copy the token code from step 2 to Access Token: Box, Then Query "me/accounts", you will see your page show as JSON data on the box on the right. You will see "access_token". Copy that access_token code and use debugger tool you will see that the Expires should show Never. Use that token when you create post to facebook page with life time access.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, when I click on "Get Access Token" , goto Extended Permission, then check "offline_access", click ok. It is not remember the offline_access.

That’s because offline_access does not exist any more.

> And there are no "deprecate offline_access" in advance of the app.

The migration is not available any more, because the process of deprecation has been finished with removal of the permission.

> If someone can make it work, please share!

Please do some **research!**

The deprecation of offline_access and how to handle it has been discussed here over and over again.

Start here, https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/, and then search SO or the web if there are still things unclear to you.

Comment: Thanks to CBroe.

I visited that link few times before I post my question. After I visit again I found the solution at "Scenario 5: Page Access Tokens".